# How to make a multiple rows editable in react native

Tags: react-native

How to make multiple rows editable. I am using the following code.

```
{this.state.poProducts.map((item, index) => {
              console.log(item)
              return (
                <View style={[{ flexDirection: "row" }]}>
                  <QHText title={item.name} />
                  <QHInputView1
                    keyboardType="number-pad"
                    textStyle={{ color: undefined }}
                    placeholder="quantity"
                    value={''+item.qty}
                    placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
                    onChangeText={(qty) => {
                       console.log(qty)
                       // this.state.poProducts[index].qty = qty;
                       item.qty = qty
                       console.log(qty, item)

                    }}
                  />
                </View>
              );
            })}
```

This is dynamic data.. we can not know exactly how many rows there.. when I edit this approach, the record is not updated. Is there any way to update records?

Answer (score 0):

use editable in TextInputs tag and assign them a boolean variable if the editable action is requested then set the boolean variable as true and this would make all the textInputs (in which this variable is assigned to editable) editable e.g.

```
<TextInput ... editable={readOnly} />
 ...
<TextInput ... editable={readOnly} />
```